# Parse ProtoBuff file to object list

Tags: c#, parsing, protocol-buffers

Hi I have a protobuff TXT file like this:

```
parameter {
  name: "Key1"
  value: 0
}
parameter {
  name: "Key2"
  value: 1.5
}
parameter {
  name: "Key3"
  text: "Value 3"
}
parameter {
  name: "Key4"
  arr {
    val: 0
    val: 2000
    val: 2050
    val: 2100
    val: 2150
    val: 2200
    val: 2250
    val: 2300
    val: 2350
    val: 2400
    val: 2400
    val: 2400
    dim: 12
    dim: 1
  }
}
```

I was trying to parse it with this [library](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net)

Current tryout code:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Parameter
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { set; get; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public double Value { set; get; }
}
public class FileParser
{        
    public static Parameter[]  Parse(string filePath)
    {
        List<Parameter> parameters;
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            parameters = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Parameter>>(file);
        }

        return parameters?.ToArray();
    }
    private FileParser()
    {

    }
}
```

I am new to Proto-Buff so I don't know if I am even going in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes suggest protobuf-net; protobuf-net only implements the *binary* protocol, not the opinionated JSON protocol. As such, you'll need to use the Google protobuf implementation, by running the schema (.proto) through protoc. Note that protoc is also available by changing the drop-down here: https://protogen.marcgravell.com - just in case that saves you having to download any additional tools.